# Error SQL Syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-insert

hi im rather new to SQL and im currently trying to save some data into a Sql database using a website. But everytime i run it i get some Syntax error and now after many hours of looking i was hoping somebody in here knew an answer, or could lead me in the right direction :)

this is the error i get when i hit my submit button : 
`0You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[Campus one],[101],[2016-12-08],[test])' at line 1`

this is the insert part of the script, connection part seems to be running fine

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `formel`(`Område`, `Værelse`, `Dato`, `TV Fjernsyn Forlænger`) VALUES ([$area],[$filnavn],[$dato],[$Fjernsyn]) ";
```

SQL information:

[image: Picture of database]

Comment: after changing to @BenM answer it worked, but it started getting the "unknown column in fieldist error, but i figured it was properbly due to the speciel letters, i removed thoese and tried with dato and fjernsyn and when i press submit it goes completely white, no errors but when i look in my DB there isnt any input :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your values need to be changed from:

`[$area],[$filnavn],[$dato],[$Fjernsyn]`

to:

`'{$area}','{$filnavn}','{$dato}','{$Fjernsyn}'`

You should really be binding your params though. I assume you're using mysql_ which you shouldn't be using anymore therefore I also suggest you look into mysqli_ or PDO.

**Edit:**

You should move over to PDO in fairness, I did and I love it!

I work with classes a lot as it's a neater way to work so I'll give you my input:

Make yourself a dbConfig.php file:

```
class Database
{
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "dbName";
    private $username = "username";
    private $password = "password";
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection()
    {

        $this->conn = null;
        try
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

So because i am half lazy and why type code over and over?

Create yourself a dbCommon.php file.

```
class DBCommon
{
    private $conn;

    /** @var Common */
    public $common;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $database = new Database();
        $db = $database->dbConnection();
        $this->conn = $db;
    }

    public function runQuery($sql)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
```

Then you need a class file for your PDO to go into such as:

class.update.php:

```
require_once('dbCommon.php');

    class Update extends DBCommon
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function updateCode($area, $filnavn, $dato, $Fjernsyn)
        {

            $stmt = $this->runQuery("INSERT INTO `formel` (`Område`, `Værelse`, `Dato`, `TV Fjernsyn Forlænger`) VALUES (:area, :filnavn, :dato, :Fjernsyn)");
            $stmt->bindParam(array(':area' => $area, ':filnavn' => $filnavn, ':dato' => $dato, ':Fjernsyn' => $Fjernsyn));
            $stmt->execute();
            echo "Your insert command has been completed!";


        }
    }
```

Then within your file.php where you would be calling the class you need to do:

```
require_once ('class.update.php');

$update = new Update();

if (isset($_POST['send']))
{
    $update->updateCode($_POST['area'], $_POST['filnavn'], $_POST['dato'], $_POST['Fjernsyn']);
}
```

**Note:** Because you didn't post your `$_POST['name']`'s in I have given you a base example.

Binding your params is best practice as this prevents SQL Injection.

With binding params you dont have to run `$stmt->bindParam();` You can simply run `$stmt->execute(array(':paramshere' => $paramVar));`

It totally depends on your preference but I always prefer binding before executing (personal preference). I hope this gives you some input and insight on how to move into PDO instead but it really is the way forward.

Comment: after making theese changes i get this error : 0Unknown column 'område' in 'field list'

Comment: i figured it was proberbly due to the speciel signs æøå and decided to remove område and værelse, and now the error is gone, and it just goes to a white screen, but when i look inside my database nothing shows :(

Comment: i actually managed to get it to post something now :) so problem solved, but do any of you know why it wouldnt accept the speciel letters because its kinda depended on it :(

Comment: mysql isn't great with utf8 columns

Comment: I think it might be an idea to add a simple example of using a prepared statement to this answer for completeness.  If you add one I'll upvote :)

Comment: @GordonM, I hope my revision is good enough as a PDO example :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to prevent [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), you should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), or correctly escape your strings. Please look at [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Here's a basic tutorial using PDO and Prepared Statements inside of PHP:

```
// Connect to the database:
$db = new PDO( 'mysql:dbname=DB_NAME;host=localhost', 'DB_USER', 'DB_PASS' );

// Prepare the statement:
$ins = $db->prepare( 'INSERT INTO `formel` (`Område`, `Værelse`, `Dato`, `TV Fjernsyn Forlænger`) VALUES (:area, :filnavn, :dato, :Fjernsyn' );

// Execute with bindings:
$ins->execute(array(  
    ':area'     => $area,
    ':filnavn'  => $filnavn,
    ':dato'     => $dato,
    ':Fjernsyn' => $Fjernsyn
));
```

Comment: +1 for prepared statement, which is almost always the far superior way of handling a query that needs parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `formel`(`Område`, `Værelse`, `Dato`, `TV Fjernsyn Forlænger`) VALUES ('$area','$filnavn','$dato','$Fjernsyn') ";
```

I think it should work.

Comment: At least until somebody sets $Fjernsyn to `Robert'); -- DROP TABLE students;--` at any rate :) https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `formel`(`Område`, `Værelse`, `Dato`, `TV Fjernsyn Forlænger`) VALUES ('$area','$filnavn', '$dato', '$Fjernsyn') ";

But I would suggest you use prepared statement for security purposes